# how to call classes and functions from different files in python

Tags: python, function, class, module

I'm trying to call function of different class which is in different file.

```
import test_db #test_db: name of different file

obj=test_db.testDb('config.ini') #testDb:Name  of class
db_cmd = "Select top 1 * from db.name"
obj.query_exec(db_cmd,'db') #function in class testDb
```

Error I'm getting is

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'testDb'
```

test_db file

```
class testDB:
    def __init__(self,config_file):
        self.config_file=config_file
        self.parser=SafeConfigParser()
        self.parser.read(config_file)
# Create connection
    def sql_db_conn(self,tst):
        ser_name=self.parser.get(tst,'machine-name')
        db_name=self.parser.get(tst,'database')
        user=self.parser.get(tst,'username')
        passwd=self.parser.get(tst,'password')  
        con = pypyodbc.connect(driver="{SQL Server}",server=ser_name,database=db_name,uid=user,pwd=passwd)
        cur = con.cursor()
        return cur

    def query_exec(self,query,sample_db):
        cur=self.sql_db_conn(sample_db)
        res =cur.execute(query)
        for r in res:
            print (r)
```

Comment: You need to show us the `test_db` module if you expect us to know what's in it, which in turn is a part of figuring out why you can't use it the way you expect.

Comment: please provide your `test_db` file.Otherwise just a guess. `import .test_db` may fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class name in statement `obj=test_db.testDb('config.ini')` is wrong.
It should be statement `obj=test_db.testDB('config.ini')`

Answer (score -1):

```
from testDb import *

a = testDB("config_file_name")  
a.query_exec("db_cmd")      

# using a object we can access all functions in that class
```